Right to Left WordPress (Farsi) Changing the Order of Taxonomy to Term in URL
Using WordPress Farsi(Right to Left), I am seeing an issue in my URL which is instead of rendering the URL as  Domain/Taxonomy/Term/ format

I am getting  in reverse order as  Domain/Term/Taxonomy/

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix this?
